# How to properly handle asyncio.TimeoutError? Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` for a script that needs to send out many concurrent HTTP head requests and collect the results. When an exception occurs on one of the head requests it is immediately propagated to the task that awaits on `gather()` as per the `asyncio` documentation. When I catch an exception, I need to cancel all other tasks and retry from the beginning. This seems to work with the `aiohttp` exceptions, but behaves weird when there's an `asyncio.TimeoutError`

See the example code here:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import logging
import time

async def fetch_content_length(session, url):
  async with session.head(url) as resp:
    return resp.content_length

async def content_lengths(session, url):

  endpoint = url + '{}'

  tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_content_length(session, 
    endpoint.format(i))) for i in range(500)]

  try:
    results = [await coro for coro in asyncio.gather(*tasks)]
  except (aiohttp.ClientResponseError, aiohttp.ClientConnectionError, 
      asyncio.TimeoutError):
    for t in tasks:
      t.cancel()
    raise

  return results

async def all_content_lengths(session):

  urls = ['https://www.example.com/', 'https://www.example2.com/', 
    'https://www.example3.com/']

  tasks = [asyncio.create_task(content_lengths(session, url))
    for url in urls]

  try:
    results = [await coro for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks)]
  except (aiohttp.ClientResponseError, aiohttp.ClientConnectionError, 
      asyncio.TimeoutError):
    for t in tasks:
      t.cancel()
    raise

  return results

async def run():

  connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True)
  session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, raise_for_status=True)

  try:
    for retry in range(1, 6):
      retry_time = 2 ** retry
      try:
        results = await all_content_lengths(session)
      except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as e:
        logging.info(f"Failed with {e.status} on {e.request_info.url}")
        time.sleep(retry_time)
      except aiohttp.ClientConnectionError as e:
        logging.info(f"Failed with: {e}")
        time.sleep(retry_time)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        logging.info("Failed with timeout")
        time.sleep(retry_time)
      else:
        return results
    else:
      logging.warning("All retries failed")
  finally:
    session.close()

def main():
  results = asyncio.run(run())
```

Whenever there's an `asyncio.TimeoutError`, I would except my program to cancel all other tasks and retry with a clean slate. It does successfully retry, but in my logs I get this error:

```
WARNING: Failed with timeout
ERROR: Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-891068' coro=<content_lengths() done, defined at example.py:10> exception=TimeoutError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 18, in content_lengths
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "example.py", line 7, in fetch_content_length
    async with session.head(url) as resp:
  File "example-project\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "example-project\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 634, in _request
    break
  File "example-project\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 721, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

Sometimes there's 2 of the same error in a row, before retrying successfully. I don't understand the `Task exception was never retrieved` error. The first raised exception should trigger the cancel loop of all the other tasks, or am I wrong? Does it have something to do with other tasks also raising the timeout error exception? I'm scratching my head here.